# Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:VS2019DEVENV' in section 'Product:*'

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2019

I am getting this error "Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:VS2019DEVENV' in section 'Product:*'" In my Wix setup project I tried the following solutions

- Updated Wix toolset version into the latest 3.14
- Added reference of WixVSExtension.dll into the setup project

I changed VS2019DEVENV to VS2017DEVENV and build is succeeded for vs2017. Please find the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
# This comment is generated by WixEdit, the specific commandline
# arguments for the WiX Toolset are stored here.

candleArgs: 
lightArgs: "<projectname>.wixobj" -out "<projectname>.msi" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.14\bin\WixVSExtension.dll"
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
 <?define PRODUCT_VERSION="14.0.0.1" ?>
 <?define MANUFACTURER="sample"?>
 <?define PRODUCT_NAME="test"?>
<?define UPGRADE_CODE="{8F258A2B-2203-43C2-A63C-B829E552F327}"?>
 <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.PRODUCT_NAME) v$(var.PRODUCT_VERSION)" Language="1033" Version="$(var.PRODUCT_VERSION)" Manufacturer="$(var.MANUFACTURER)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UPGRADE_CODE)">
<Package Compressed="yes" />
<PropertyRef Id="VS2019DEVENV" />
```

Comment: Looks like updating broke the connection between your database and the application.  See : https://support.wix.com/en/article/creating-a-content-collection

Comment: How is this related to C#? If not related, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The version of wix binaries is my problem and I updated those with v3.14

[image: Wix edit]

and updated the path in build settings also

".wixobj" -out ".msi" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.14\bin\WixVSExtension.dll"